# How can I know if the request to the servlet was executed using HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, https, http-protocols

I wrote a servlet in Java and I would like to know if the request to that servlet was executed using HTTP or HTTPS.

I thought I can use `request.getProtocol()` but it returns HTTP/1.1 on both methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

***HttpSerlvetRequest.isSecure()*** is the answer. The ServletContainer is responsible for returning true in the following cases:

- If the ServletContainer can itself accept requests on https.
- If there is a LoadBalancer in front of ServletContainer. And , the LoadBlancer has got the request on **https** and has dispatched the same to the ServletContainer on **plain http**. In this case, the LoadBalancer sends ***X-SSL-Secure : true*** header to the ServletContainer, which should be honored.

The Container should also make this request attributes available when the request is received on **https**:

- javax.servlet.http.sslsessionid
- javax.servlet.request.key_size
- javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate

Comment: Can you please share where did you get 'X-SSL-Secure : true' bit? I keep searching and I cannot find more info on this header.

Comment: This does not work on my environment: Apache 2.4.10 as front proxy; it iseems to be impossible to know in java, wheter the request has been done with http or https to apache. Sure, I get it as http to Java, but I need to know, how the front proxy has been accessed. - Indeed, as @Zotov also mentioned: There is almost no info about X-SSL-Sercure header. So I assume this is not widly implemented?!

Comment: The header name may differ since it is not very standard. But, the  concept here is that the proxies can add headers about the SSL and the servers can read them. For Ex, Nginx adds X-SSL-Protocol. It can replaced with custom header also.

Comment: I guess, you use any specific Load Balancer as f5 and the "X-SSL-Secure : true"  is an optional header, which is not part of any (even not load balancer) standard, right?

Answer (score 29):

You can't reliably depend on port numbers.
But you can depend on the scheme:

Use: [request.getScheme()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme%28%29) to see if it is `https`.

If it is then it is secure connection.

I believe this should work regardless of Tomcat version

Comment: isSecure goes back to at least [1.2](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29), and is not Tomcat-specific.

Answer (score 11):

[isSecure](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29).  Be sure to check the inherited methods.