# Why does request.getRequestURL() return non-https url?

Tags: jsf, servlets

In one of our projects we still have to use JSF 1.2 + Tomcat 6 and the problem is when I'm sending `https`-request to the server and trying to get requested URL in the managed bean as follows:

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString()
```

The button that sends the request is just a submit-button looked as follows:

```
<h:form id="contactform">
    <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{forgotPasswordBean.doSend}"
 </h:form>
```

I get `http`-based URL intead of `https`.
In the web-browser's debug panel I made sure that an `https`-request was actually sent, but URL contained a link to just `http` request. What's a problem or it's just a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestUrl()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) contains the protocol, server name, port number and server path, i.e. it should contain `https` if the connection is actually secured and is under HTTP.

However, this is not the only way to determine if the connection is secured. The [`ServelRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) interface defines two more options ([`ServletRequest#getScheme()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme%28%29) and [`ServletRequest#isSecure()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure())) to detect if the request is secured or not:

```
String scheme = request.getScheme(); //will return "https" when connection is secured
//or
boolean isSecured = request.isSecure(); //will return true when connection is secured
```

More info:

- [How to check if the request to a Servlet is secured or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200853/how-can-i-know-if-the-request-to-the-servlet-was-executed-using-http-or-https)

Comment: Actually, the problem was that we have a load-blancer that sends plain-http request.

Answer (score 18):

This behavior can happen if you have a load-balancer in front of the application. Even though requests are done in HTTPS the load-balancer will reissue them as plain http requests which produce this behavior.

One example is when using GAE (Google App Engine). You can use an HTTPS endpoint (https://my-app.appspot.com) but your app will continue to receive all requests in HTTP.

*This was pointed out by @user3663882 under comments of approved answer.*

Comment: A good loadbalancer passes at least some additional http header that indicates it was a secure connection