# Session Management when part of an application is over http and some part on t https

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, cookies, session-cookies

I have an application (J2EE) which is partly on HTTP and partly on HTTPS. I want to have two session cookies to track a user, one when he on a HTTP page and other for HTTPS page.

I want the HTTPS cookie to secure and http-only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you have to call `setHttpOnly(true)` , `setSecure(true)` on your cookie before sending it to client. Secure cookies are transfered via HTTPS or SSL.

Comment: well, this won't work. the cookie intended for HTTP will be sent to HTTPS requests too.

Comment: I agree , but I think we'll be able to figure out the request type and set the cookie . pl check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200853/how-can-i-know-if-the-request-to-the-servlet-was-executed-using-http-or-https