# faces-redirect uses http and not https

Tags: jsf, https

Regarding the use of faces-redirect=true and redirecting to https, I've seen various techniques here on how to solve that, but can someone provide the explanation of why it redirects to http instead of https ?

Comment: Because the server that actually processes the request runs in "http mode"  or does not know how to process information that comes from the request that it originates in https. Most likely your server is behind a front-end reverse proxy. Effectively making this a 'servlet container' issue and not a jsf one. Create a simple servlet that does a redirect and you'll face the same problem/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156100/redirecting-not-working-with-https (effectively it is a duplicate)