# How to fix HTTPS-HTTP mixed content error in JSP redirection in a java web application

Tags: java, http, jsp, https, http-redirect

I am using a DNS url (https) which is a load balancer url for my web application which is hosted in Weblogic server. When I hit the url in chrome and I can do a successful login. Then when I am trying to click on some button from the page , say some view/edit button, there is no response. When I debugged I found it is due to mixed content issue in chrome. Yes I don't face any issue in IE and Firefox for the same.

When I am using the raw http url in stead of the DNS url, I have no issues.

Now, I want to fix this issue in my jsp itself. But I am  not sure about the code changes that I need to make.

Following are the URLs that I get from network trace :

```
Console URL : https://dns-host/myapp/console.jsp
Request URL : https://dns-host/myapp/editWorkSelector.jsp?workid=1234&copywork=view
Referer     : https://dns-host/myapp/workDataScr.jsp?workname=null
Location    : http://dns-host/myapp/workView.jsp
```

I am trying to go to workView.jsp in my code. Here I face the issue and unable to go to the page.

Here is  a sample code :

File :  workDataScr.jsp

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="<%=bgcolor%>">           
    <a href="editWorkSelector.jsp?workid=<%=id%>&copywork=view" 
       onClick="return checkForSystem(this.form,'<%=id%>','<%=type%>','<%=role%>')">VIEW
    </a>
</td>

function checkForSystem(form,workid,worktype,role){
   form = document.forms[1];
   form.action="editWorkSelector.jsp?workid="+workid+"&type="+worktype;
   form.submit();
}
```

File : editWorkSelector.jsp

```
 String workid = request.getParameter("workid");
 String copy = (String)request.getParameter("copywork");
 String workname = (String)request.getParameter("workname");
 WorkData work = workBean.getWork(workid);

 response.sendRedirect("workView.jsp");
```

Here lies the issue, due to mixed content the code flow is unable to reach workView.jsp.

Error :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dns-host/myapp/console.jsp' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure resource 'http://dns-host/myapp/workView.jsp'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
enter code here
```

It will be very helpful to know how to fix this issue in my code.

Comment: I might need to use a custom filter which can help me to redirect the response to https. I am trying to write it. Got some useful links. Let me try.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a similar issue.

Comment: Yes the problem is fixed. I will update the answer.

Comment: @I.R. : Answer added. Please check now. If it works for your case [which I dont know] pls dont forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to redirect the request on conditions properly before executing the below line.

```
response.sendRedirect("workView.jsp");
```

Hold the schema/referrer like below :

```
String scheme      = request.getScheme();
String referer     = request.getHeader("referer");
```

It is better to use referrer because schema doesn't always give the desired result. You can check the value in console debugger.

Then execute the redirect on condition like this :

```
String servername  = request.getServerName();
String scheme      = request.getScheme();
String referer     = request.getHeader("referer");

if(referer.startsWith("https")) {
    response.sendRedirect("https://" + servername + "/context-root/" + "workView.jsp");
}else{
    response.sendRedirect("workView.jsp");
}
```